# Aggregating variables for cases

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello fellow Overflowers,

the goal is to process certain steps of data manipulation on a fairy big dataset. In a first step, certain variables, which represent different cases of a certain information, shall be aggregated for each case. There are always 5 variables to aggregate.

Right now, the dataset looks like this:

```
      a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 ... xyz5 A B C 
case1 3  4  7  9  6  21 13              4    1 7 8 
case2 9  12 8        17 25 31           7    2 7 6
case3 5  3  11 10    32 19 13           5    1 6 8
...
```

It should somehow look like this

```
      mean-a  mean-b ...mean-xyz A B C 
case1 5,8     17        6,4      1 7 8 
case2 9,6     24,3      8,3      2 7 6
case3 7,25    21,3      7        1 6 8
...
```

I'm not sure if building a function or using the `across`function from the `dplyr` package is the right way to do it, since there are about 2000 variables which need to be aggregated.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# First we extract the unique letter values of column names
letters <- unique(str_remove(names(df), "\\d"))
[1] "a" "b"   
  

# Then we iterate over each unique values and extract the columns that contain that unique letter

letters %>%
  map(~ df %>% 
        select(contains(.x)) %>% 
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate("mean_{.x}" := mean(c_across(contains(.x)), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  bind_cols() %>%
  relocate(contains("mean"), .after = last_col())


# A tibble: 3 x 12
# Rowwise: 
     a1    a2    a3    a4    a5    b1    b2    b3    b4    b5 mean_a mean_b
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     3     4     7     9     6    21    13     7     8     4    5.8   10.6
2     9    12     8    17    25    31     4     2     2     7   14.2    9.2
3     5     3    11    10    32    19    13     2     2     5   12.2    8.2
```

**Data**

```
df <- tribble(
  ~a1, ~a2, ~a3, ~a4, ~a5, ~b1, ~b2, ~b3, ~b4, ~b5,
 3, 4, 7, 9, 6, 21, 13, 7, 8, 4, 
 9, 12, 8, 17, 25, 31, 4, 2, 2, 7,
 5, 3, 11, 10, 32, 19, 13, 2, 2, 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Example Data:

```
# toy data
library(data.table)
m <- matrix(1:30, ncol = 10)
colnames(m) <- c(paste0('a', 1:5), paste0('b', 1:5))
d <- data.table(m)
d
   a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
1:  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28
2:  2  5  8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29
3:  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
```

#### Determine Groups:

You can determine first the groups you want to aggregate.

```
groups <- split(colnames(d), gsub("\\d", "", colnames(d)))
groups
$a
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5"

$b
[1] "b1" "b2" "b3" "b4" "b5"
```

#### Aggregate

Afterwards you simply calculate the mean of each group.

```
> d[,lapply(groups, function(i) {rowMeans(d[, i, with = FALSE])})]
   a  b
1: 7 22
2: 8 23
3: 9 24
```